# Is this polymorphism?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I recently was in an interview and during that interview I realized my programming concepts aren't as concrete as I thought.

I was asked, describe a time in your previous job where you used polymorphism?

After some thinking I said that we had a record class which every new record extended. So if we have a AddRecord or a RemoveRecord or any other type of record, they would extend Record. The record interface looked something like this:

```
public abstract Record{
  public writeLine(String line);
  public getColumn(int column);
  public setHeader(String header);
  ...
}

public AddRecord extends Record{
  public writeLine(String line){
      // do something
  }

  // etc...
}

public MakeRecord{
   Record r;
   public setRecord(Object s){
      if(s instanceof Record){
          r = s;
      }
   } 

   public void printNewRecord(){
      while(thingsToWrite){
          r.writeLine(something);
      }
   }
}
```

I just shorthanded it so don't nit pick it please.

I told them this was using polymorphism because regardless of the record type, it could be wrote without knowing what type of record it was. This was valuable because we are writing files that needed to be padded correctly, either zero filled or padded with spaces etc...

If this isn't polymorphism, please tell me how I can change my example into something that uses polymorphism.

Comment: Did the interviewer tell you that wasn't polymorphism? (If the answer is "yes", proceed to the next interview without looking back.)

Comment: Looks good to me, maybe your concepts are actually better than you think.  Sometimes interviewers will play dumb mind games to test your level of conviction.  Reviewing this stuff ahead of time never hurts.

Comment: (well, except for that `instanceof` check.. what's that doing there?)

Comment: Ok thanks guys. I think he was playing dumb but it felt like he didn't believe me but it was over the phone :)

Comment: I did the instanceof check to make sure the object passed in was correct. Is that not needed?

Comment: A better choice would be to make the method `setRecord(Record s)`, then you'll get a *compile* error if you pass the wrong thing (this is what you want). With the way your code is now, you'll get no compile error, no runtime error, and your code probably won't do what you want.

Comment: As @Greg notes the more problems you can trap at compile-time, the better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long answer short: yes
Polymorphism is, according to webster:a (1) : existence of a species in several forms independent of the variations of sex (2) : existence of a gene in several allelic forms (3) : existence of a molecule (as an enzyme) in several forms in a single species b : the property of crystallizing in two or more forms with distinct structure

we are focused with definition a. this describes, in java terms, as using 1 "top" class to reference two "bottom" classes. That is shown in the above example, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Are the biology definitions really necessary here? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) offers a fine definition of polymorphism in an OOP context.

Comment: instead of asking, I made it community wiki for a reason. if you think it would help better put differently, then do it.

Answer (score 1):

A very basic example of polymorphism:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestClass{
  public static void main(String args[]) {
     ArrayList animals = new ArrayList();
     animals.add(new Bear());
     animals.add(new Fish());
     animals.add(new Animal());
     for (Animal a : animals){
         a.someMethod();
     }
  }
}

class Animal {
   public void someMethod(){
      System.out.println("I am an Animal");
   }
}

class Bear extends Animal{
   public void someMethod(){
      System.out.println("I am a Bear");
   }
}

class Fish extends Animal{
   public void someMethod(){
      System.out.println("I am a Fish");
   }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
I am a Bear
I am a Fish
I am an Animal
```

So we can see here that the loop calling the methods on each type of object calls them all on Animal, and yet the actual method called on each object is that objects own implementation of that method.

Clearly for this to work every object in the collection MUST have an implementation of this method, although it can obviously use the superclass’ version if that is appropriate for that object.

This means that the objects in a collection (as an example of how it may be used) can be decided at runtime, and don’t have to be individually type cast back to their true form, but can simply be called by a parent class type or interface type. This allows for far more flexibility in the code, and makes it easier to maintain. It also allows for code which is more generic and loosely coupled.

So there it is in a nutshell. There are tons of examples online to have a look at. It’s a brilliant concept, and one which is well worth investing some time into understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The example is not good for explaining polymorphism.

Addrecord is not good extension of Record class. Addrecord should be method and not a class.

So basically you should have Record class having Addrecord method and this method can be overriden by special records like - *ColumnnameRecord*.

In the case where you have specialRecord class derived from Record class and Record Class have methods which are overriden by derived classes then you have good examples of polymorphism.

Current example is technically correct but not conceptual correct.

Answer (score 0):

Another example for Polymorphism:

```
abstract class PolyGeometricEntity
{
    public int center_x__mm;                    // commen superset
    public int center_y__mm;                    // commen superset
    public void move(int d_x__mm, int d_y_mm)   // commen superset
    {
        center_x__mm += d_x__mm;
        center_y__mm += d_y_mm:
    }

    public abstract int area();                 // commen superset on abstract level, but specialized at implementation level
    public abstract void draw();               // commen superset on abstract level, but specialized at implementation level
}

class CircleEntity : PolyGeometricEntity
{
    public override int area()
    {
        // circle specific
        return 1;
    }
    public override void draw()
    {
        // draw a circle
    }
}

class TriangleEntity : PolyGeometricEntity
{
    public override int area()
    {
        // triangle specific
        return 1;
    }
    public override void draw()
    {
        // draw a triangle
    }
}


class PolyCanvas
{
    List<PolyGeometricEntity> entities = new List<PolyGeometricEntity>();

    void CreateEntity(string toCreateClass)
    {
        // assume that code is called by the ui
        // you do not know what the user decides at runtime
        // Polymorphism 'starting' now:
        PolyGeometricEntity toCreate = null;
        if (toCreateClass == "c") { toCreate = new CircleEntity(); }
        else if (toCreateClass == "t") { toCreate = new TriangleEntity(); }
        entities.Add(toCreate);
    }

    void ReDraw()
    {
        foreach (PolyGeometricEntity toDraw in entities)
        {
            toDraw.draw(); // polymorphism in action!
        }
    }
}
```